# Failure accessing a folder using ssh.net

Tags: c#, unix, appium, ssh.net

I have a .Net application that sends commands to Mac via SSH using SSH.Net library and I seem to have a problem accessing certain folders in Mac.
I am trying to access a file under /usr/local/bin/ folder and getting the following error:
 env: node: No such file or directory
Now, I am pretty sure this file exists.. 
When I am trying to run an "ls" command from the application I see the following folders:

- Applications
- Desktop
- Documents
- Downloads
- Library
- Movies
- Music
- Pictures
- Public
- node_modules

Tried changing Folder's permission and it didn't seem to help. 
The application uses the same user as the Mac itself so I am pretty sure the folder should be visible to that user.
Thanks!